# Nine-dimensional central division algebras over $\mathbb Q$ that are not cyclic algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that (finite-dimensional) central division algebras of dimension $n^2$ over $p$-adic fields are cyclic algebras over the unique unramified extension of degree $n$ of the base field.

(Also, yes, finite-dimensional simple algebras over number fields split globally if and only if they split locally everywhere...)

And I vaguely recall that *not* every finite-dimensional central division algebra over $\mathbb Q$ is constructible as a cyclic algebra over a cyclic extension of $\mathbb Q$, for example.

But I have failed to find a reference for that... I'd appreciate further facts and/or references! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a pointer from Mauriano Suarez-Alvarez, I looked in Richard Pierce' "Associative Algebras" (Springer, 1982), which both answered my immediate question, and reminded me of some things that I should not have forgotten.

First, as in 15.6 in that source, all division algebras of dimension $3^2$ over their center are cyclic (for characteristic not $3$).

In 15.7, A. Albert's construction of a non-cyclic division algebra of dimension $4^2$ over its center is given. All this is "pure algebra".

What I'd somehow forgotten is the Albert-Hasse-Brauer-Noether theorem and its corollaries, treated in chapter 18 of that source: every central simple extension of a number field is cyclic. Wow! Yes, this uses much serious stuff, e.g., Grunwald-Wang, classfield theory, and so on, which are not proven in Pierce' book.